# Hyperlink in textbox same as like message composer screen in windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I had an textbox in which user can enter text and there was an list box below the text box which shows the collections of objects of a class. When user selects any one of the list box item i am displaying the list box item in the textbox using the text property in the selected event of the list box. Now my concern here is i want to make the selected list box item as hyperlink in textbox which is clickable same as like in message composer in windows phone. And user can continue typing the text in the textbox after item was selected to select the next list box item. Can any one help me to find the solution.

Comment: I am not displaying as hyperlink now.just i am showing selected item text in textbox. but now i want it to be as hyperlink which is clickable in textbox. Yes when the back key is pressed i would like to delete the whole content of selected item same as like in message composer which as semi colon fro each selected contact

Comment: after selecting listbox item the selected list box item should appear as hyperlink in the textbox. is it clear now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yea its clear now. Can you check
this link 'http://www.jayway.com/2011/10/05/wp7-link-in-text-with-richtextbox-on-mango/'

Hope this will help you. 
 
 You can try this way.

```
        <TextBlock x:Name="tbref" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
        <RichTextBox >
            <RichTextBox.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <HyperlinkButton  x:Name="txtnam" Content="{Binding  Text,ElementName=tbref}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        <TextBox  Width="200"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </RichTextBox.Template>
        </RichTextBox>
```

selection event handler

```
        private void lst_SelectionChanged_1(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
         var selectedString = lst.SelectedItem;
         tbref.Text = selectedString.ToString(); 
        }
```

Comment: Thank you. But in rich textbox we can place some text as hyperlink. But i cannot allow my user to type the text in rich text box to select the items.

Comment: i think we can't use hyperlink inside textbox content. RichTextBox is better to do that.

Comment: yes.In rich textbox we can place some text as hyperlink.Its fine upto there but we cannot type text in rich textbox same as like in textbox. but i need to type some text to select the an item from listbox.. Is it possible in rich textbox.

Comment: @SwethaBindu I have updated by answer .Hope you can do like that way with some adjustment.